# Absolute and relative permitivitty

Tags: theory, materials

Principles of Electronic Materials and Devices - Hasap, pg: 585, he says:

$$\epsilon_r = \frac{Q}{Q_0} = \frac{C}{C_0} = \text{relative permittivitty}$$

Then he says:

> It is important to remember that when the dielectric medium is
>   inserted, the electric field remains unchanged, provided that the
>   insulator fills the whole space between the plates as shown in Figure
>   7.1c. The voltage V remains the same and therefore so does the gradient V/d, which 
>   means that electric field E remains constant.
>   [image]

But I thought the reason we had absolute and relative permittivitty is because the material affects the strength of the electric field with \$\epsilon_0\$ being absolute permitivitty (free space). Also how is he getting that (above) equation, given that:
\$C = (\epsilon_0 \times A) / d\$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electric field strength will change if the charge is fixed. But in your case, a dielectric is inserted between two parallel plates connected to a battery.

So charge carriers will flow from battery to the plates to compensate for this change in electric field because battery has to maintain the voltage across the plates constant (\$V=E\times d\$).